# How to add code google analytics with tvml, tvjs

Tags: tvos, tvml, tvjs

I want include google analytics in my app.

Here code:

```
var return_doc  = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>           
<document>  
                            <head>  
                              <script type="text/javascript">  
                              var _gaq = _gaq || [];  
                              _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX']);  
                              _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);  
                              (function() {  
                              var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;  
                              ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';  
                              var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);  
                              })();  
                              function timerTracking()  
                              {  
                                  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview'])  
                                  t=setTimeout("timerTracking()",900000);  
                              }  
                              timerTracking();  
                            </script>  
                            <style>  

                            </style>  
                            </head>  
                            <stackTemplate
```

But it not working.
Can you guide to use this?

Answer (score 1):

TVML doesn't have support for the script tag to inline JS in your templates.

Instead, you should include the JS script inside your main JS file (where you have `App.onLaunch`).

Note that, TVML/TVJS doesn't have 'pages', so page views won't track like they would on web. Also, the Javascript environment is different to a browser, with some API's not available, so the Google Analytics library might not work with TVJS out of the box.